# How to use XDocument to update existing xml file which has namespace requirements?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linq-to-xml

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://a01_data_navin" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://a01_data_navin event.xsd">
  <Event>
    <eventid>1</eventid>
    <Photo>
      <filepath>files\images\memory rep02.png</filepath>
      <location>
        <lat>35.496456056584158</lat>
        <lon>-99.228515625</lon>
      </location>
      <datetimestamp>2020-03-29T00:00:00</datetimestamp>
    </Photo>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <eventid>2</eventid>
    <Photo>
      <filepath>files\images\poop.jpeg</filepath>
      <location>
        <lat>36.137874718407268</lat>
        <lon>-89.6044921875</lon>
      </location>
      <datetimestamp>2020-03-29T00:00:00</datetimestamp>
    </Photo>
  </Event>
</Root>
```

When i use XDocument in C#

```
 XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(_xmlFilePath);
            // create xml structure
            var photo_XML =  tempPhotoList.ToArray();

            xml.Element("Root")?.Add(
                new XElement("Event",
                    from photo in photo_XML
                    select new XElement("eventid", photo.EventId),
                    from photo1 in photo_XML 
                    select new XElement("Photo",
                        new XElement("filepath", photo1.FileNameForPath),
                        new XElement("location", 
                            new XElement("lat", photo1.GetLatitude()), 
                            new XElement("lon", photo1.GetLongitude())),
                            new XElement("datetimestamp", photo1.DateTimeStamp)
                    ))
            );
```

When i run the above code i cant seem to enter into the xml file and iterate the tree. I would have to add a name space like this:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(_xmlFilePath);
            // create xml structure
            var photo_XML =  tempPhotoList.ToArray();

            xml.Element(NameSpace+"Root")?.Add(
                new XElement("Event",
                    from photo in photo_XML
                    select new XElement("eventid", photo.EventId),
                    from photo1 in photo_XML 
                    select new XElement("Photo",
                        new XElement("filepath", photo1.FileNameForPath),
                        new XElement("location", 
                            new XElement("lat", photo1.GetLatitude()), 
                            new XElement("lon", photo1.GetLongitude())),
                            new XElement("datetimestamp", photo1.DateTimeStamp)
                    ))
            );
```

With adding the `Element(NameSpace+"Root")`; im able to traverse through my xml file and add a new event but i end up with this..

```
<Event xmlns="">
    <eventid>3</eventid>
    <Photo>
      <filepath>files\images\poop.jpeg</filepath>
      <location>
        <lat>17.140790393316649</lat>
        <lon>1.7578125</lon>
      </location>
      <datetimestamp>2020-03-29T00:00:00</datetimestamp>
    </Photo>
  </Event>
```

I need some help on how to add or update a new event into an existing xml file which has namespace to deal with; using XDocument in C# ? It seems that using XDocument gets my task done.

Im stuck guys.. please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(_xmlFilePath);
            XElement root = xml.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();


            root.Add(new XElement(ns + "Event",
```

Comment: Thank you and this solved my question in hand. You are a wonderful person. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey everyone so this is what i did to resolve the issue in hand..

*I added namespace to every XElement instead of only at the root.. Sorry rookie mistake from before.. :P

```
         XElement root = xml.Root;
         XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            root.Add(
                new XElement(ns+"Event",
                    from photo in photo_XML
                    select new XElement(ns +"eventid", photo.EventId),
                    from photo1 in photo_XML 
                    select new XElement(ns +"Photo",
                        new XElement(ns +"filepath", photo1.FileNameForPath),
                        new XElement(ns +"location", 
                            new XElement(ns +"lat", photo1.GetLatitude()), 
                            new XElement(ns +"lon", photo1.GetLongitude())),
                            new XElement(ns +"datetimestamp", photo1.DateTimeStamp)
                    ))
            );
```